# What is the best practice to manage HTML pages modified by jQuery.append()?

Tags: jquery, html

I needed to implement one of those search result pages where pagination is made clicking a button that adds new results at the bottom of the page (they get back as HTML code from a Web Service). Whatever this kind of pagination is called in webdev jargon, I noticed it has a "problem": being the new content added modifying the DOM, when I make a HTTP request to another page and then I go back to the previous (using the browser's *back button*) the added content is no longer visible and I see the original page as it was received (and cached) by the browser.

As a solution, I was thinking to ask again for all the results fetched before leaving the page, but I have a quite annoying question in mind: I'm wondering if this solution goes under the definition of "poor design".

I'd appreciate very much if you experts could give me both an opinion and an advice on how to request for the results again because I cannot figure out what event I can rely on to trigger the call to the WS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referring to an "infinite scroll" or load schema where the user only sees a subset and then on some event (click or scroll) more of the superset is loaded.

This content is loaded through ajax and not through the first get request of the page. When browsing back, the get method's return value was cached, and that is the display you see. There are some ways to get around this and call a fresh request. However, the result is the same, that a get request is returned and not the current page state.

In order to facilitate this you would need to maintain a page state which can be kind of daunting. Lets look at the most widely used version of this on the web today: facebook's photo browsing. Even if you dynamically load hundreds of images, if you refresh or navigate away and then back, all you get is that first set.

It is basically understood that if you loaded a bunch of content, and hit back, as a user you will need to start over. While this is unfortunate there is a good reason behind it. While browsing as a user you spend time waiting for these ajax calls and they are small. If you were to have to wait for the sum total on a page load that wait time could be significant. Load times are the reason why this isn't done in the wild.

I would say there is nothing wrong with your current approach. Have the user re-create or re-browse their dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your comment. In the meanwhile I was thinking about a reasonable solution to achieve my goal. It popped up in my mind the Local Storage feature of the most recent web browsers. I could store the last number of documents fetched and then call the WS and get all the results or (why not) store the whole HTML in there and avoid a call to the WS. What would you suggest?